# Auto program resizer

Tags: windows, automation

There are a lot of programs, which cannot remember what was its last window size. I need a program, which works in the background, and I can configure it, to resize all launched programs/windows on the fly.

For example, if I open my SSH client, I want it to auto resize its window to a given size. When I open another application I want it to auto resize/position it.

Is there such a tool in the wild? The prog called 'Auto Window Manager' just doesnt fit my needs. And I dont want to write autohotkey / etc. scripts for each prog I launch, so I need a generalized solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: "The prog called 'Auto Window Manager' just doesnt fit my needs." - how so?

Comment: Because it just does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [WinSize2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/), it's made with AHK.

For each program you can save settings by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Z. When you launch the program next time it will be moved to saved position with saved size.

Comment: Does WinSize2 support tool windows?