# Is there a way to save the layout of various programs and explorer windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, layout

I'm using Windows 7 and I've got a few common things I do on my computer and each require a specific layout of the windows.  For example, one might have Firefox open on the left side of the screen, a certain folder open below that, and a certain Excel sheet open on the right.  One other example:  3 explorer windows, each for a different location, a browser, and 2 text files (open in, say, notepad).

I would like to create some kind of macro or something that could open all the windows I need, in their proper locations on screen, for each task with one click.  If that's not possible, what's the least amount of work possible?

I'd ideally prefer not to have to install any special software, but I'd consider that.

Comment: one minor tip, because windows will re-open a program often where it was Closed last, but not a second instance of it, creating 2 physical instances of the executable can work in a few cases. notepad.exe notepad2.exe, each with thier own location stored on exit.  AHK can move windows and set size using scripting.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/201714/auto-program-resizer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but if you have an AMD graphics card, then I would at least look into [hydravision](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/hydravision.aspx). I only used it for like 5 minutes, but I seem to recall that its pretty close to what you want.